# Redirect to third party url using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm very much aware of the react-router-dom I want to do a conditional rendering of the component. If use is not logged in redirect him to some third party URL

for example, the below code looks neat and works fine

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={() => (
  isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Redirect to="/front"/>
  ) : (
   <Home />
  )
)}/>
```

Let's say in the above example if I want to redirect `to` **https://www.google.com** how can I do it?

if I write

```
 <Redirect to="https://www.google.com"> it gives me error.
```

How can I redirect to a third party website?

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71240842/12276108 Answered on the link provided

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a tag for external urls,

```
<a href='https://domain.extension/external-without-params'>external</a>
```

but also you can provide component like this:

```
<Route path='/external' component={() => { window.location = 'https://domain.extension/external-without-params'; return null;} }/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `window.open()` to redirect to any website.

For example:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

implement redirection in your code:

```
render () {
  if(this.isLogin) {
    return(/* your components*/);
  } else {
    window.open('https://www.google.com');
    return (<div></div>); //render function should return something
  }
}
```

You can also specifies the target attribute or the name of the window, for more details, see [w3school tutorial about this function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using **Typescript** you probably will get the following error with the Accepted Answer:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Location'
```

To fix that you just need to use window.location.href

```
<Route path="/external" component={() => {window.location.href = config.UPGRADE_URL return null }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have on mind that you cannot perform that with `<Link />` or `<NavLink />` since they're mainly for routing throughout Single Page Application.

You should use anchor tag instead.
Example: `<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>`.