# Open external link with function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes

I'm trying to create a button in React which opens an external link to a google maps url.

I have a function which asks the user for their geolocation, which once provided, inputs the location into the url link which gets directions from their geolocation to a set destination.

However, I'm struggling to get the button to firstly run the function and open the URL in a **new tab**. This is currently how I'm calling the button component.

```
<Button variant="primary" onClick={this.onHandleClick}>Get Google Maps Directions</Button>
```

And this is the function which forms and opens the link.

```
  onHandleClick = () => {
    var location = this.state.currentLocation;

    location.then(function(location){
      var link = `google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=${location}&destination=50.927044,-1.299964&travelmode=driving`      

      //window.location.href = link;
      window.location.assign(link);
    })
  }
```

Currently the external link forms correctly, but is appended to the existing localhost domain in the url so does not open currently (or in a new tab).

url result of the above functions:

http://localhost:3000/google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=50.4984,%20-2.6119074&destination=50.927044,-1.299964&travelmode=driving

I've tried setting target="_blank" when calling the compnent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Max

Comment: have you tried window.open? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 15):

```
window.open(link, "_blank");
```

This will cause the link to open in a new tab.

Note: If you do not include "http://" or "https://" before the link, the default behavior is to append the link onto the current domain, so if you're opening an external link, be sure to include the http/s.

Comment: Simple and concise 

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! Using window.open does open the link in a new tab, but it's still appending the url to the end of localhost - any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: @max You should go ahead and mark this answer as correct, as it worked. I've updated it to include the https bit.

Answer (score 4):

Answering in case it helps any people of the future...

As suggested by @user2950720, window.open method correctly oepns the link a new tab.

To stop the link from appending to localhost/, ensure to inlcude 'https://' at the start of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
window.open(link, "_blank");
```

it will open a new window tab but if its keep on adding your site base url at the start just use // at the start of the linnk
like

```
window.open(`\\${link}`, "_blank");
```

it will open new window and will not add base url of site