# Redirect to a different website using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect with the icons to a different social media websites but it goes back to my home page maybe the url or redirections are wrongly placed?

```
<div class='social-icons'>
            <Link
              class='social-icon-link facebook'
              href = 'https://www.facebook.com/Atlakamani2017/'
              target='_blank'
              aria-label='Facebook'
            >
              <i class='fab fa-facebook-f' />
            </Link>
            <Link
              class='social-icon-link instagram'
              href='https://www.instagram.com/atlakamanisurfingresort_/?hl=en'
              target='_blank'
              aria-label='Instagram'
            >
              <i class='fab fa-instagram' />
            </Link>
            <Link
              class='social-icon-link twitter'
              to='/'
              target='_blank'
              aria-label='Twitter'
            >
              <i class='fab fa-twitter' />
            </Link>
          </div>
```

Comment: Why not just use `<a>` tag instead of `Link` it results in the same base HTML, but you get the ability of `href`.

Comment: interesting, I'll try that right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to third party url using react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103291/redirect-to-third-party-url-using-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 2):

To correct, I just needed to change the `<link>` tag for an `<a>` tag, and worked like a charm!

```
<a
  class='social-icon-link facebook'
  href='https://www.facebook.com/Atlakamani2017/'
  target='_blank'
  aria-label='Facebook'
>
```

Thanks [Ameer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340895/redirect-to-a-different-website-using-react#comment120781651_68340895)